# How to know if the user entered more than one char in an input window

Tags: c, char, scanf

I need to write a code that can print an error message if the user entered more than one char in an input/output window and I'm only allowed to use 'scanf'

Comment: Show us what code you've come up with yourself so far.

Comment: "input window"  are you using some kind of GUI?  Please post a [mcve], including the details of what problem your trying to solve

Comment: `scanf` only deals with standard input. so it is impossible it gets the input from a text field in an input/output window... what do you mean exactly with a input/output window?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
Take input as a string, check if it's length is greater than one.

Method 2:
Run a loop inputing char ch till ch is not the end of line, maintain a counter i. Check if I is greater than 1(in case started with char)

Method 3:
If you want to just take input a char, and ignore other characters than declare a char ch and input it, the computer will ignore it.